# Turn by turn within MKMapView on iOS 6

Tags: iphone, xcode, navigation, routes, mkmapview

I wondered if it is possible to create navigation route within MKMapView on iOS 6 instead of opening the built-in Maps application?
I googled it but didn't find any answer.

This is the code I'm using now (that is opening the built-in Maps app):

```
-(IBAction) navigation
{
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"6.0"))
    {
        NSString *destinationString = @"Afek, Israel";
        NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%@",wedMapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude,wedMapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude, destinationString];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    }

    else
    {
        Class mapItemClass = [MKMapItem class];
        if (mapItemClass && [mapItemClass respondsToSelector:@selector(openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:)])
        {
            double latitude = 32.83431728836292;
            double longitude = 35.128666162490845;
            MKPlacemark *placemark = [[[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude) addressDictionary:nil] autorelease];
            //[mapItem setName:@"Name of your location"];

            // Create a map item for the geocoded address to pass to Maps app
            MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
            [mapItem setName:@"שמורתה, קיבוץ אפק"];

            // Set the directions mode to "Driving"
            // Can use MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeWalking instead
            NSDictionary *launchOptions = @{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving};

            // Get the "Current User Location" MKMapItem
            MKMapItem *currentLocationMapItem = [MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation];

            // Pass the current location and destination map items to the Maps app
            // Set the direction mode in the launchOptions dictionary
            [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:@[currentLocationMapItem, mapItem] launchOptions:launchOptions];
        };
    }
}
```

And this is the MKMapView I Have that I want to make turn by turn route when I press the blue map button (above the Waze button):

[image: MKMapView]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 6 does not provide the app with directions, it relies on the built-in Maps app to do that. So if you want to show directions with in your app you'll need to find a service for calculating the route. You can't use Google because they only allow you to use their data on their maps, not on Apple's. You could look into CloudMade and OpenStreetMap, but you'd have to give up using iOS 6's maps for that. They come with their open UI components.

Comment: Got my answer...
Thanks Craig!